# Python NameError: name '_mysql' is not defined

Tags: python, mysql, django, ubuntu

I am trying to have a working ubuntu server with Python, Django and MySQL. But when I switch from SQLite to MySQL and trying to reach my server I get the following error "NameError: name '_mysql' is not defined".

It does work if I run the project in virtual environment mode with the command "python manage.py runserver". The database is also correctly created with the command "python manage.py migrate". This does not work when I try to reach my URL. I think there is an issue with my virtual host file, but I am unable to see it. Any help would be appreciated!

**Virtual host file:**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mysite.com
    ServerAlias www.mysite.com

    WSGIDaemonProcess myprocess python-path=/var/www/myproject/myname:/var/www/myproject/myname/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages 
    WSGIProcessGroup myprocess    
     
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/myproject/myname/myproject/wsgi.py

    <Location / >
      Order deny,allow
      Deny from all
      # ek
      Allow from ${IP_USER1}
      Allow from ${IP_USER2}
    </Location>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

**The error log:**

```
    mod_wsgi (pid=55852): Failed to exec Python script file '/var/www/myproject/wsgi.py'.
    mod_wsgi (pid=55852): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/myproject/myname/myproject/wsgi.py'.

    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/var/www/myproject/myname/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from . import _mysql
    ImportError: cannot import name '_mysql' from partially initialized module 'MySQLdb' (most likely due to a circular import) (/var/www/myproject/myname/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py)

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/var/www/myproject/myname/myproject/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
    application = get_wsgi_application()
    File "/var/www/myproject/myname/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
    django.setup(set_prefix=False)
    File "/var/www/myproject/myname/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
    File "/var/www/myproject/myname/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 115, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
    File "/var/www/myproject/myname/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 211, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 850, in exec_module
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
    File "/var/www/myproject/myname/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
    File "/var/www/myproject/myname/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py", line 47, in <module>
    class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
    File "/var/www/myproject/myname/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 121, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, app_label))
    File "/var/www/myproject/myname/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 325, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
    File "/var/www/myproject/myname/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 208, in contribute_to_class
    self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
    File "/var/www/myproject/myname/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 28, in __getattr__
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
    File "/var/www/myproject/myname/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 207, in __getitem__
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
    File "/var/www/myproject/myname/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 111, in load_backend
    return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
    File "/var/www/myproject/myname/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 16, in <module>
    import MySQLdb as Database
    File "/var/www/myproject/myname/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    version_info, _mysql.version_info, _mysql.__file__
    NameError: name '_mysql' is not defined
    mod_wsgi (pid=55852): Failed to exec Python script file '/var/www/myproject/myname/myproject/wsgi.py'.
    mod_wsgi (pid=55852): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/myproject/myname/myproject/wsgi.py'.

    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/var/www/myproject/myname/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from . import _mysql
    ImportError: cannot import name '_mysql' from partially initialized module 'MySQLdb' (most likely due to a circular import) (/var/www/myproject/myname/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py)

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/var/www/myproject/myname/myproject/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
    application = get_wsgi_application()
    File "/var/www/myproject/myname/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
    django.setup(set_prefix=False)
     File "/var/www/myproject/myname/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
    File "/var/www/myproject/myname/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 115, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
    File "/var/www/myproject/myname/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 211, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 850, in exec_module
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
    File "/var/www/myproject/myname/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
    File "/var/www/myproject/myname/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py", line 47, in <module>
    class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
    File "/var/www/myproject/myname/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 121, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, app_label))
    File "/var/www/myproject/myname/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 325, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
    File "/var/www/myproject/myname/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 208, in contribute_to_class
    self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
    File "/var/www/myproject/myname/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 28, in __getattr__
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
    File "/var/www/myproject/myname/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 207, in __getitem__
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
    File "/var/www/myproject/myname/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 111, in load_backend
    return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
    File "/var/www/myproject/myname/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 16, in <module>
    import MySQLdb as Database
    File "/var/www/myproject/myname/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    version_info, _mysql.version_info, _mysql.__file__
    NameError: name '_mysql' is not defined
```

**The wsgi.py file:**

```
"""
WSGI config for myproject project.

It exposes the WSGI callable as a module-level variable named ``application``.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/deployment/wsgi/
"""

import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'myproject.settings')

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

**The requirements.txt file:**

```
asgiref==3.5.2
Django==3.0
mysqlclient==2.1.1
pytz==2022.1
sqlparse==0.4.2
typing_extensions==4.2.0
```

Comment: usually this kind of error can suggest that you didn't install C/C++ server MySQL

Comment: I see one strange think: error show paths with `/python3.7/` and with `/python3.9/` - it looks like you mess with two different Pythons.

Comment: I would install Python module [suggested by MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-installation-binary.html). They creates this module.

Comment: Thank you @furas! The issue was the wrong python version. I created a new virtualenv with python version 3.9 and it worked. Can you maybe explain why this an issue? Is it not possible to have a different version inside the virtualenv and the installation on ubuntu?

If you add your suggestion as an answer I can mark it as solved :)